# Ubuntu 14.04 installation crashes with "???" message after selecting drive

Tags: boot, 14.04, partitioning, usb, system-installation

## The Gist:

I have been trying to erase my disk and install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop as my sole operating system. I can boot "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" from a USB stick. During the graphical install, after I select "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" as my installation type, I have a choice to select between one of two RAID0 drives on which to install Ubuntu. (One is 18.2GB and the other is 439GB, so I naturally pick the larger one.) Regardless of which drive I select, one of two bad things generally happens.

In the first case, I get an error message saying "???" as soon as I proceed to the next screen. In the second case, I successfully manage get past the next screen, get 75% of the way through installing updates and packages, and then the installer crashes.

## Precisely what I did before reaching this state:

1. Downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) 64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop
   image.
2. Ran md5sum on the file and checked that it matched the hash on
   Ubuntu hashes. It matched correctly.
3. Used [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) (on Windows) to format my USB drive
   (FAT32) and mount the image on my drive.
4. Re-booted with the USB drive plugged in, entered the boot menu, and
   selected "Try Ubuntu." Ubuntu successfully loads.
5. Clicked icon on desktop labeled "Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" to open
   Graphical Installation.
6. Chose all recommended options up until the screen that says
   "Installation type", where I selected "Erase disk and install
   Ubuntu."
7. I then had a choice between two drives on which to install Ubuntu:
   an 18.2GB drive labeled RAID0RST and a 439.2GB drive labeled
   RAID0SYS. I selected the larger drive.
8. I reach a time zone screen, then an error message saying "???"
   appears. I can't click anything. My screen goes black and freezes. I
   tried this installation approach a few different ways, each time
   with the same result.
9. At this point, I wanted to start over fresh, so I opened GParted,
   deleted all of my partitions, and rebooted as before. When I do
   this, I usually manage to get past the screen with the "???" message
   successfully, although the installation crashes 75% of the way
   through installing updates at the end.
10. Now I have two different partial Ubuntu installations on my boot
     menu, both of which I can open. However, I don't trust either of
     them because both show several obvious signs of an incomplete
     installation.

## Potentially relevant info (partitions, hardware, etc):

### Partitions info

Running

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

produces the following warnings:

```
**WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

WARNING:  GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on  '/dev/mapper/isw_dbdbgfbgbe_RAID0SYS'! The util fdisk doesn't support  GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_dbdbgfbgbe_RAID0SYS2 doesn't contain a valid partition table

WARNING:  GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on  '/dev/mapper/isw_dbdbgfbgbe_RAID0SYS3'! The util fdisk doesn't support  GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_dbdbgfbgbe_RAID0SYS3 doesn't contain a valid partition table

WARNING:  GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on  '/dev/mapper/isw_dbdbgfbgbe_RAID0RST'! The util fdisk doesn't support  GPT. Use GNU Parted.**
```

and the following output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   964690431   482345215+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sdb: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x695f6563


Disk /dev/mapper/isw_dbdbgfbgbe_RAID0SYS: 493.9 GB, 493921501184 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60049 cylinders, total 964690432 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

                              Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/isw_dbdbgfbgbe_RAID0SYS1               1   964690431   482345215+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_dbdbgfbgbe_RAID0SYS1: 537 MB, 537657344 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 65 cylinders, total 1050112 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

                                Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_dbdbgfbgbe_RAID0SYS2: 484.9 GB, 484913971200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 58954 cylinders, total 947097600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/isw_dbdbgfbgbe_RAID0SYS3: 8469 MB, 8469348352 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1029 cylinders, total 16541696 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc62b49f5


Disk /dev/mapper/isw_dbdbgfbgbe_RAID0RST: 18.2 GB, 18181521408 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2210 cylinders, total 35510784 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

                              Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/isw_dbdbgfbgbe_RAID0RST1               1    35510783    17755391+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdc: 15.6 GB, 15610576896 bytes
119 heads, 55 sectors/track, 4658 cylinders, total 30489408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *        8064    30489407    15240672    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

### Hardware

Asus Zenbook Ux51Vz-XH71
Brand new, sexy.
Came with Windows 8 Pro 64-bit out-of-the-box.
Specs are listed [here](http://www.asipartner.com/128854.html).

PNY 16GB USB 2.0 stick (P-FD16GATT03-GE).
New.
FAT32 formatted out-of-the-box.

#### EDIT: I mostly resolved my issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492057/two-partition-tables-are-unrecognized/492074#492074). (See comments in the Hannu's answer.) My only remaining issue is that I have duplicate ubuntu entries in my boot menu.

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/492074/289138) may be one way out of your predicament.