# Two partition tables are unrecognized

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, uefi, raid, gpt

While trying to installing Ubuntu 14.04 as my sole operating system, I've been encountering a number of issues (Described in more depth at [Ubuntu 14.04 installation crashes with "???" message after selecting drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491840/ubuntu-14-04-installation-crashes-with-message-after-selecting-drive)), all of which seem to be related to GPT and RAID, both of which I know little about.

When I open GParted, I get an error message. Upon Xing out the error message and checking /dev/sda and /dev/sdb, I see that they are unrecognized.

My laptop is an [Asus Zenbook UX51Vz-XH71](http://www.asipartner.com/128854.html), which comes with two SSDs (2x128GB or 2x256GB) in an Intel Rapid Storage (aka Intel Matrix) RAID 0 configuration and uses UEFI and GPT. Here is what the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_Zenbook_UX51Vz) says:

> The UX51Vz comes in a variety of configurations, most of those sold in western Europe come with two SSDs (2x128GB or 2x256GB) in an Intel Rapid Storage (aka Intel Matrix) RAID 0 configuration. To install Arch Linux on the UX51Vz, you can follow the official Installation guide. Since the UX51Vz uses UEFI and GPT, make sure to also read the UEFI, GPT and UEFI_Bootloaders pages. It is recommended to use rEFInd as a bootloader and mount the EFI partition on /boot. To prepare a UEFI USB device, read UEFI#Create_UEFI_bootable_USB_from_ISO. The only way to preserve the pre-installed Windows instance is to install Arch with RAID without breaking up the RAID 0 array. See RAID with the only difference that you should not create arrays, only assemble.
>   Note: As of BIOS version 207 on UX51VZH there is no option to reconfigure the Intel RST setup through BIOS. Once you break your array, you cannot set it up again. For Linux-only users, mdadm software raid should be a better option.

I have deleted all partition tables using GParted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say that you "wish to scrap what there is earlier" (if I understand you correctly) you seem to have the option to either set up a raid (as it appears to have been as you got it) or use the SSD disks as separate storage devices.

The latter should be the easier option.
In that case I'd suggest you click on "Unallocated space" as shown in the image above, then select `Device > Create Partition table` (from menus), which leaves you with one pending operation (`View > Pending operations` shows the list).
To execute the pending operations click on the 'tick' or select `Edit > Apply all operations`
... Then it should be possible to partition that disk.

Repeat for `/dev/sdb` and the error message should disappear.
I believe it appears due to gparted not being able to recognize the data on these two disks.

Comment: That appeared to help in that it was able to recognize those two drives, although it didn't appear to create a partition tables within the devices, so that wasn't enough to resolve my installation issue. For anyone else who encounters a similar problem, I resolved my installation issue by creating my own partition tables from scratch within the devices including 300MB for an EFI boot loader, 10 GB of swap space, and the rest of the first SSD for my /home folder. For the second SSD, I just mounted to a folder I called /data.

Comment: My only remaining concern is that, when I open my boot menu, I see two different instances of ubuntu, which both load the same thing.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes more sense. Well, it looks like the first and second entries appear to do exactly the same thing?

Comment: Creating a partition table is one thing, creating partitions within it another - the latter is what you did to be able to install things. There should be two entries in the boot menu, the second is to open a new menu with options to boot a specific kernel (updates will bring in new ones), and do recovery - if the system gets into a bad state of some sorts.

Comment: Sorry for removing the earlier comment - put it back with an addition. Do the menu entries *say* exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, they say exactly the same thing.

Comment: Boot option priorities
Boot Option #1 [ubuntu]
Boot Option #2 [ubuntu]

Comment: That looks strange, the second should have "Recovery mode" or some such (from memory). And selecting it should open a new menu, not boot the machine. In [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/489181/289138) answer is four lines, boot, open a terminal with SHIFT+CTRL+T and run the **last two lines** (sudo update-initramfs -u ; sudo update-grub2). That MIGHT reset things to normal state. NOte: I'll be leaving now - midnight here ;-)